# Is it ambiguous to use both partial derivative operator "$\partial$" and the "Einstein's" notation of gradient $\partial$ the same time in one paper?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

Similar to Einstein, many applied math papers use the notation "$\partial$" as the gradient operator. For example, $\partial f(x)$ means the gradient of $f$ at $x$.

$x$ is a vector.

In my paper I need to use both partial derivative and gradient. For example, consider the following three equivalent expressions:

1. $\frac{\partial\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i}$
2. $\partial_{x_i}\partial f(x)$
3. $\partial_{x_i}\nabla f(x)$

Will the first express cause any ambiguity to readers as the two "$\partial$" symbols have different meanings? Which expression is the least ambiguous one?

You are welcome to supply your own favorite notation, too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use the subscript after the comma $_{,\ i}$ to denote (partial) differentiation wrt $x_i$. So, e.g., $$\partial f_{ij,\ k}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{k}}(\partial f_{ij})\ .$$

Comment: Yes your notation is the most original and "authentic" Einstein's notation.